# jQuery replace multiple texts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some advice for my text replacement using jQuery. I have a template that looks like this and builds a shoppingcart:

```
{foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
                    <div class="product">
                        <span class="product-image"><img src="{$product.cover.small.url}"></span>
                        <div class="product-details">
                            <h2 class="name-header">{$product.name}</h2>
                            <div class="product-quantity-details">
                                <span class="quantity">{$product.quantity}</span>
```

This will give me a container for each product, there are more elements after and before. I have some buttons that can increase or decrease the quantity (`.product-quantity-details .quantity`). I use jQuery to send an AJAX request:

```
document.getElementById('link1').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var html ;
        $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
              html = $(data).find('.product-quantity-details .quantity').html();
              console.log(html); 
              $(".product-quantity-details .quantity").text(html);
          }
    });
});
```

The server returns a HTML representation of the whole cart (including the other items not shown in the code above). I cannot simply replace the container with the response, because there are images loaded and they don't appear if I use `jQuery.replaceWith()`. So currently I only can update one quantity.
Is there a way to update each quantity, so get an array of values from `$(data).find('.product-quantity-details .quantity').html();` where I can iterate trhough and replace the exisiting text in the HTML?
Or is there a better way to achieve my gaol (update any amount of quantities in my HTML). 
I thought of simply using `html = $(data).find('.product-quantity-details .quantity');`, is there a guarantee that this array has the order of the HTML elements?

Comment: " there are images loaded and they don't appear if I use jQuery.replaceWith()"...why not? Are the image links returned by the ajax call incorrect or something?

Comment: No, If I replace them and do not reload the page they are not delivered?

Comment: well why doesn't it return the correct HTML with correct URLs to these images? That would be the issue I would investigate in this scenario. You seem to be attempting to create a workaround instead of solving the underlying problem.

Comment: No,if I just replace the HTML it works correct, the pictures are not loaded if I only replace the HTML or am I wrong here?

Comment: "if I just replace the HTML it works correct, the pictures are not loaded if I only replace the HTML"....sorry this makes no sense. You seem to be talking about "replace the HTML" in both situations. What's the difference? I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

simply use, I have not encountered any case where html elements order is not maintained. Also you have index property which will give the position number.

```
html = $(data).find('.product-quantity-details .quantity');
```